# Update non mock object when mock function is called

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

If I have a non mock object called quantity (that has an update function), and another mock called, m, how can I update the quantity object and then return it when m.doSomething() is called.
I'd like to do something like this.

```
Quantity quantity = new Quantity(1);
M m = //...another object
when(m.doSomething()).thenReturn(quantity.update(2));
```

But I can't do this because update() is void. Is there a way I can call update on quantity and then return the updated quantity?

I'm thinking of something like this

```
when(m.doSomething()).thenDo(quantity.update(2)).thenReturn(quantity);
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? This would test the behavior of the mocking frame work, but unit test should test *your* codes behavior.

Comment: I understand this. It's a little tough to explain why I want to do this, but it will help me test my code. Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Ok, put it this way. Imagine that quantity is a mock as well, and when I call m.doSomething, I want to then trigger quantity.update(). Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

> Imagine that quantity is a mock as well, and when I call m.doSomething, I want to then trigger quantity.update().

I think what you want is something like this:

```
class QuantityTest{

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    private Quantity quantity;
    @Mock
    private M m;

    Cut cut;
    @Before
    public void setup(){
      cut = new Cut(m,quantity);
   }

   @Test getsQuantitiesAsDesired(){
     doReturn(1,2).when(quantity).get(); //return 1 at first call, 2 at all others
     InOrder inOrder = inOrder(m,quantity);

     cut.doSomethingWithQuantityAndM();

     inOrder.verify(quantity).get();
     inOrder.verify(m).doSomething();
     inOrder.verify(quantity).get();
   }
}
```

But if you insist in changing `Quantity`:

```
class QuantityTest{

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();   
    @Mock
    private M m;    

    private Quantity quantity = new Quantity(1);
    Cut cut;
    @Before
    public void setup(){
      cut = new Cut(m,quantity);
   }

   @Test getsQuantitiesAsDesired(){
    doAnswer(i->quantity.update(2)).when(m).doSomething();
    // ...
```

I didn't test it so you may need the "anonymous class" form for void Answers...

Answer (score 0):

The following should be what you are looking for:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable{
        quantity.update(2);
        return quantity;
    }
}).when(m).doSomething();
```